# Creating an HTML Widget or DataTable from a list

Tags: r, list, datatables, knitr, ggvis

I have created a list and want to create an html widget in R to display it more cleanly. Currently my list is created as follows:

```
 testing <- data.frame(
  MONTH = c("MTD: 12", "MTD: 12", "Percent Change:", "MTD: 12", "MTD: 12", "Percent Change: ", "MTD: 12", "MTD: 12", "'Percent Change:"), 
  YEAR = c(2015, 2016, 2016, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2015, 2016, 2016), 
  Client = c("A.", "A.", "A.", "B.", "B.", "B.", "C.", "C.", "C."), 
  Revenue = c(500, 250, -25, 500, 1000, 50, 100, 25, 25),
  Col1 = c(651, 485, 533, 3932, 171, 436, 456, 234, 576), 
  Col2 = c(478, 335, 305, 238, 115, 251, 231, 967, 364), 
  Col3 = c(73, 69, 57, 6, 67, 57, 34, 65, 89)
)

testing
 split(testing,testing$Client)
```

Result:

```
$A.
            MONTH YEAR Client Revenue Col1 Col2 Col3
1         MTD: 12 2015     A.     500  651  478   73
2         MTD: 12 2016     A.     250  485  335   69
3 Percent Change: 2016     A.     -25  533  305   57

$B.
             MONTH YEAR Client Revenue Col1 Col2 Col3
4          MTD: 12 2015     B.     500 3932  238    6
5          MTD: 12 2016     B.    1000  171  115   67
6 Percent Change:  2016     B.      50  436  251   57

$C.
             MONTH YEAR Client Revenue Col1 Col2 Col3
7          MTD: 12 2015     C.     100  456  231   34
8          MTD: 12 2016     C.      25  234  967   65
9 'Percent Change: 2016     C.      25  576  364   89
```

I am using Knitr/RMarkdown and when I display this is doesn't look clean. Is there an html widget or a datatable that can be created in R to better the display.

I know there is the

DT package and the gvisTable but that only applies to a dataframe I am pretty sure. Anyone know how to apply something similar to a list?

Thanks

Comment: Could you sort your initial dataframe by Clients and then use the `DT` or `gvisTable` package? or do you want to display three independent tables, one for each client?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313600/r-knitr-print-in-a-loop)?

Comment: That didn't work for a list though: I tried it and it gave me this message: Error in data.frame(Client1 = list(MONTH = c("MTD: 12", "MTD: 12", "Percent Change:" : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 2