# R: why kable doesn't print inside a for loop?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I'm working a report with rmarkdown and latex. I need to print a group of tables using `knitr::kable`, but the don't print when inside a for loop.

This is my code:

````
---
title: "project title"
author: "Mr. Author"
date: "2016-08-30"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
bibliography: biblio.bib
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{tcolorbox}
---

Text and chunks that run ok.

```{r loadLibraries}
require(data.table)
require(knitr)
```

## Try to print a group of tables from split

```{r results = "asis"}
t1 <- data.table(a = sample(letters, 10, T), b = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, T))
t2 <- split(t1, t1$b)

for (i in 1:length(t2)){
    kable(t2[[i]], col.names = c("A", "B"))
}
```
````

It doesn't matter if I use `results = "asis"` or if I omit it altogether, **nothing prints to the document**.

I've tried enclosing the `kable` call within a `print` call (`print(kable(t2[[i]]...`), and it successfully prints the output to the document, but the format is the same format as a standard R prompt (preceded by `##`, for example), which is rather ugly.

How can I display the tables, other than manually?

**### EDIT ###**

Some answerers have redirected me to [R knitr print in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313600/r-knitr-print-in-a-loop) as a duplicate answer. **It's not**, because as I stated in the previous paragraph, this effectively prints the table, *but the format is not the expected one*. The accepted answer (and related github thread) really solved the problem.

Comment: Other than you describe in your second-to-last paragraph, the `print` call does the trick. I suppose you forgot to set `results="asis"` when you tried this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R knitr print in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313600/r-knitr-print-in-a-loop)

Comment: This is recommended reading to all those landing on this question: https://yihui.org/en/2017/06/top-level-r-expressions/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This question is addressed here: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/886

All you need is a line break after each print call

````
---
title: "project title"
author: "Mr. Author"
date: "2016-08-30"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
    bibliography: biblio.bib
    header-includes:
       - \usepackage{tcolorbox}
---

Text and chunks that run ok.

```{r loadLibraries}
require(data.table)
require(knitr)
```

```{r results = "asis"}
t1 <- data.table(a = sample(letters, 10, T), b = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, T))
t2 <- split(t1, t1$b)

for (i in 1:length(t2)){
    print(kable(t2[[i]], col.names = c("A", "B")))
    cat("\n")
}
```
````

Comment: I don't know about the situation in 2014, but nowadays the `cat` is not required. It's just the `print` statement that is missing in the code from the question.

Comment: Using kable instead a loop is also discussed here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html