# Kable doesn't print a table inside if..elsif...else statement

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have made this code to print different tables inside if..elsif..else statement with kable.

````
```{r}
    if (sum(df_final2$change)!=0 && nrow(df_final[is.na(df_final$PEH.1),])!=0) {
        cat("The new peptides are:\n")
        kable(df_peptides_spectra2)
        cat("Decreased or increased:\n")
        kable(df_final3)
    } else if (sum(df_final2$change)==0 && nrow(df_final[is.na(df_final$PEH.1),])!=0) {
        cat("The new peptides are:")
        kable(df_peptides_spectra2)
        cat("The rest peptides are the same.")
    } else if (sum(df_final2$change)!=0 && nrow(df_final[is.na(df_final$PEH.1),])==0) {
        cat("The are not new peptides:\n")    
        cat("Decreased or increased:\n")
        kable(df_final3)  
    } else
        cat("The number of peptides are the same\n")
```
````

Using my data frame, the condition that fulfill the conditions is the Option 2, so I expected to have this:

```
cat("The new peptides are:")
kable(df_peptides_spectra2)
cat("The rest peptides are the same.")
```

Although, my output is this, without any table. :

```
The new peptides are:
The rest of peptides are the same.
```

Do you know any way to fix this? I've tried to add a line break after each print call ([R: why kable doesn't print inside a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650166/r-why-kable-doesnt-print-inside-a-for-loop) ) but I've got the same problem.

Here you have a reproducible example:

````
```{r}



    df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), 
    .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4" ,"5") ), 
    sequence = structure(c(1L,2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), 
    .Label = c(" actgat   "," atagattg ", " atatagag ", " atggggg  ", " atgtagtt "), class = "factor"), 
    peptides = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), 
    .Label = c(" 54  ", " 84  ",  " 32  ", " 36  ", "12"),
    class = "factor"), n_project = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    .Label = " project ", class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "sequence", "peptides", "n_project"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -5L))



    if (0!=0 && (0)!=0) {
        cat("The new peptides are:\n")
        kable(df)
        cat("Decreased or increased:\n")
        kable(df)
    } else if (10==10 && 2!=0) {
        cat("The new peptides are:")
        kable(df)
        cat("The rest peptides are the same.")
    } else if (10!=10 && 2!=0) {
        cat("The are not new peptides:\n")    
        cat("Decreased or increased:\n")
        kable(df)  
    } else
        cat("The number of peptides are the same\n")


```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your reproducible example, use `print(kable(df))` to show the tables and `{r, results = "asis"}`.

````
```{r, results='asis'}

    cat("The new peptides are:\n")
    print(kable(df))
    cat("\n")
    cat("The rest peptides are the same.")

---
````

[image]

Comment: But I would like to have it in html format. I think it looks better than this one.