# kable in a function and a loop

Tags: r, knitr

I have an r markdown that calls a function. The function render another r markdown document in which I have kable inside a loop. I cannot get the kable that is called inside the loop to print.

Here is an example of code:

````
# function definition
test.kable <- function(filename){
rmarkdown::render(filename)
}

#test.rmd
```{r,echo=FALSE,results='asis'}
for(i in 1:2){
   print(kable(head(iris)))
}
kable(tail(iris))
```    

#main r markdown in which I call the function
```{r,echo=FALSE,results='asis'}
test.kable("test.rmd")
```
````

The kable inside the loop never get printed while the kable outside the loop get printed. Can anybody help me figure out how to print the kable inside the loop?

Thank you!

Comment: Try adding `include=TRUE` in the chunk options.

Comment: And see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650166/r-why-kable-doesnt-print-inside-a-for-loop it appears you have to add a line break

Comment: try `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()` first

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

````
#test.rmd
```{r,echo=FALSE,results='asis'}
for(i in 1:2){
   print(knitr::kable(head(iris)))
}
knitr::kable(tail(iris))
```
````

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, adding knitr::kable doesn't make the kable inside the loop get printed.

Answer (score 0):

In the main document, use chunk option `child` to render an external markdown document (documentation [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/)):

````
```{r child = "test.rmd"}
```
````

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, using chunk option `child` in the main document still doesn't print the kable inside the loop. Also, I need to call the function in the main document.

Comment: It works for me. You don't need the function anymore when using child.

Comment: Do you load the knitr library in test.rmd?

Comment: I'm trying to keep an R notebook and generate markdown document using other R packages. That's why, I need to call the function. I cannot just use the r child option.